Why LocalDateTime is serialized as array when return as ReponseBody in springboot?
I want to get the dates in a format of dd/MM/yyyy
so,I wrote this code first:
@GetMapping("/testAjax.json")
public ResponseBody<?> AjaxResponse testAjax(){
AjaxResponse response = new AjaxResponse();
DateTimeTest test = new DateTimeTest();
test.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());

response.addResponse("date", LocalDateTime.now());
response.addResponse("test", test);
return response;
}`

and I got this response:
{"status":false,"response":{"date":[2024,10,21,11,12,20,417960408],"test":{"dateTime":[2024,10,21,11,12,20,417940363]}}}
Tried by adding
@Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        module.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(formatter));
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return jsonConverter;
    }
    

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }

But not working,

What is AjaxResponse for class? You shouldn't be registering MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter no need to do so. The JavaTimeModule is automatically registered and with newer Jackson versions not even needed anymore. So if this isn't working you added something that disables parts of the spring boot auto configuration or have created your own ObjectMapper or something like that).

it is just a wrapper
`public class AjaxResponse {
private boolean status;
private Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}`


Please don't add code as comments, instead edit your question and improve it with more information. You also only answered the first part of the comment not the remainder of it.

Also make sure you have added spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=true to your application.properties.

maybe this code solve your problem:
String result=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").format(localDateTime);


this will solve issue of a single variable, i want to configure this in application level

@Hamzashameem problem is you try to return the local date time in that format, now you force it to return back to normal

I remember encountering this issue before especially when i comes to timestamps and date types in Restful api response ... ,The best thing you can do is to serialize your attributes of date and time by JsonFormat in your entity:
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDateTime date;

creating a Date class mapper is no longer required in Spring Boot since the auto-configuration manager that automatically but in you really need to serialize and deserialize Localedate manually try this :
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();

        module.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, 
            new com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer(
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
            ));
        
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, 
            new com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer(
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
            ));
        
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }
}

